# PHP: string got a substring, show that string

Tags: php, ftp

I get a whole list of arrays with different strings, and I want that the strings which contain "_pmx" be put in my dropdown list.

```
    $buff = ftp_nlist($conn_id,"BackupFiles");
        echo "<select id='pmxbestand' name='pmxbestand'>";
        foreach($buff as $i=>$value) {
                $resultaat = strstr($value, '_pmx');
                echo "<option value='".$resultaat."'>".$resultaat."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
```

I thought this would do the trick, but it turns out it doesn't, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substr_count:

```
$buff = ftp_nlist($conn_id,"BackupFiles");
echo "<select id='pmxbestand' name='pmxbestand'>";
foreach($buff as $i=>$value) {
        if (substr_count($value, '_pmx') > 0) echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get a whole list of arrays with different strings, and I want that the strings which 
>   contain "_pmx" be put in my dropdown list.

How about:

```
foreach( $buff as $i => $value ) {
      if( ( $result = strstr( $value, '_pmx' ) ) !== false ) {
          printf( '<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', $result );
      }
}
```

*EDIT*: Had a syntax error.